# Help plotting a trip to the Moon!

Tags: the-moon, space-travel

## Take me to the moon!

I know this is *literally* rocket science but, I would like any **sources** or **formulas** that would help me **plot a trip to the Moon**. **I'm not sending anything, nor do I ever plan to**, I just want to do the next best thing by plotting the trip. So if anyone could give me any info as to how I can plot the trip, that'd be great! :)

P.S. I'm perfectly aware that the moon isn't always the same distance away, that it's like hoping onto a taxi in New York City, and how it's got *a lot* of work (I wouldn't mind doing it really), I'd just like to plot the trip. And please don't hate on me for asking, let's just be **civil adults** here. :)

Comment: This is a bit hypothetical for Astronomy, but probably more so even for physics and I'm not sure if it would fit space exploration either? Anyway, what kind of information are you looking for exactly? How to calculate the length of the trip and the future location of the Moon at that time?  How to get there quickly? Delivery of a specific payload? Using an existing ship or some hypothetical ship? Minimizing costs? Maximizing stay period?

Comment: I would like info as to/or like how NASA did it in Apollo 11 with the Saturn V

Comment: the Dover book by R.R, Bate at al: [Fundamentals of Astrodynamics](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/0486600610/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_1?pf_rd_p=569136327&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0486497046&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_r=0F8SP9TMQGMC7J45K5SK) should do it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about space exploration http://space.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This website](http://braeunig.us/apollo/apollo11-TLI.htm) has a mathematical in depth analysis of the Apollo 11 translunar trajectory. It looks to be a reasonably reliable resource but I've only had a quick skim through so you should check on the sources cited.
There should be enough information there to make a computer program to calculate the orbits.